# iphone Netwerk Access Point

Tags: iphone

everyone how to set  Netwerk Access Point by iphone code??  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for network.

http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-testing-network-reachability/